# file exist in the directory, but getting "No such file or directory: 'I_90-0-109_(90).txt'"

Tags: python, error-handling, file-not-found, labeling

I am a beginner with the Python. I am trying to run the following code to replace some labels in .txt annotation files.

```
import os

for txt_in in os.listdir(r"/home/masoud/masoud/Dataset/PID-CORRECTED/uncorrected-YOLO_darknet"):#https://www.newbedev.com/python/howto/how-to-iterate-over-files-in-a-given-directory/ 
    with open(txt_in) as infile:# In addition, it will automatically close the file. The with statement provides a way for ensuring that a clean-up is always used.
        for line in infile:
            word=line.split(" ")[0]#spliting the string and returning an array and returing the first item of array
            if word=="6":
                word.replace('6', '5')#should i use if statement?
            elif word=="9":
                word.replace('9', '6')
            elif word=="10":
                word.replace('10', '7')
            elif word=="11":
                word.replace('11', '8')#how does it close one txt and open the next one?
                #If the break statement is inside a nested loop (loop inside another loop), the break statement will terminate the innermost loop.
            else:
                continue
            break
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-10f3bd0ebffc> in <module>
      2 
      3 for txt_in in os.listdir("/home/masoud/masoud/Dataset/PID-CORRECTED/uncorrected-YOLO_darknet"):#https://www.newbedev.com/python/howto/how-to-iterate-over-files-in-a-given-directory/
----> 4     with open(txt_in) as infile:# In addition, it will automatically close the file. The with statement provides a way for ensuring that a clean-up is always used.
      5         for line in infile:
      6             word=line.split(" ")[0]#spliting the string and returning an array and returing the first item of array

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'I_90-0-109_(90).txt'
```

It seems can find the .txt files inside the addressed directory, if so why is it saying `No such file or directory: 'I_90-0-109_(90).txt'`?
plz help. tnx!

Comment: should you choose a format for ' with open(txt_in)', like 'r' or 'w'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `os.listdir` only lists the filenames and does not include the directory. So you need to prepend the directory name to it yourself:

```
dirname = "/home/masoud/masoud/Dataset/PID-CORRECTED/uncorrected-YOLO_darknet"
for txt_in in os.listdir(dirname):
    with open(os.path.join(dirname, txt_in)) as infile:
        # do stuff with infile
        ...
```